# Concatenate cells with a delimiter but skip empty (not blank) cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, excel-2016

I've got a peculiar issue that I cant seem to solve, I want to concatenate all the text values in a specified range, minus any blanks. The values themselves are a result of an IF formula so I couldn't output blanks and therefore TEXTJOIN wont play nice with the empty spaces.

This is what I'm getting my values from:

[image: This is the what I'm getting my values from]

This is where they output, all I'm using is a TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, {array}):

[image: This is where they output]

And this is the formula I used to create the values from the first picture

I'm searching another array of letters right above it and just finding when unique values begin if that makes sense...

[image: And this is the formula I used to create the values from the first picture]

The end result I want is to have it all joined with commas and no empty " , , ,"'s. Exactly like the first row of the second picture. I included the formula i used to get the values because maybe the best way is to change it. Any help would be appreciated, more than welcome to provide more context if needed =).

And if this could be easily done with VBA I'm down for that too, I've been meaning to start learning.

Comment: I think it's better to focus on the IF formula that's producing the non-blank returns. I think it may result in `" "` instead `""`

Comment: Please post formulas as text, not pictures.

Comment: "The values themselves are a result of an IF formula so I couldn't output blanks" || Correction : you can. `=IF(A1 = 1, A2="",A2="hello")` || Please share if the text join works after you had done this...

Answer (score 1):

Oh my goodness, it was just a late night error, in the formula in the picture I had it outputting " " not "", once I changed that it all works just fine, thank you all for the help!